# What are Norms in Elastic/Lucene use for beyond scoring?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I don't use scoring on searches I'm running.  I do use ordering, but by date and other fields, of course.  I was thinking about turning off norm storing, calculating, etc.  But I haven't found an answer that describes all usages of Norms.

Beyond scoring, what are norms used for by elastic/lucene?

Answer (score 0):

norms can be turned off when you dont use them for scoring.

From [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html):

you don’t need scoring on a specific field, you should disable norms on that field. In particular, this is the case for fields that are used solely for filtering or aggregations.